# How do I stop blank output from FOR XML PATH in SQL server for dynamic sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, metadata, dynamic-sql, for-xml-path

I was trying to generate a script for data vault, below is the dynamic sql that would generate tables for many to many relations:

```
DECLARE @LOAD_DATE_RS VARCHAR(100)
SET @LOAD_DATE_RS = 'LOAD_DATETIME DATETIME NOT NULL,' + CHAR(10) 
                    + 'RECORD_SOURCE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,'+CHAR(10)
DECLARE @CREATE_LINK_M_N_RELN VARCHAR(MAX)                  
SET  @CREATE_LINK_M_N_RELN = (SELECT    
                                'CREATE TABLE LINK_'+ REPLACE(HL.TABLENAME, ' ', '_') + CHAR(10)
                                + '( '
                                    + ( SELECT  
                                            DISTINCT FPR.PK_TABLE + '_ID  INT NOT NULL,'+ CHAR(10)
                                        FROM    
                                            FK_PK_REF FPR
                                        WHERE   
                                            FK_Table IN (   SELECT 
                                                                HL2.TABLENAME 
                                                            FROM 
                                                                HUB_OR_LINK HL2 WHERE HL2.HUBORLINK= 'LINK'
                                                                AND HL2.TABLENAME = HL.TABLENAME)
                                        FOR XML PATH (''))
                            --GET PRIMARY KEYS --HAS SOME PROBLEMS
                            +(  SELECT  
                                    DISTINCT C.COLUMN_NAME 
                                    + ' '+ C.DATA_TYPE      
                                    +   CASE WHEN C.DATA_TYPE IN('CHAR','VARCHAR','NVARCHAR') THEN 
                                            '('+CAST(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(100))+')'
                                        ELSE 
                                            ' ' 
                                        END 
                                    +','+ CHAR(10)
                                FROM    
                                     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C 

                                WHERE   
                                    C.TABLE_NAME = HL.TABLENAME
                                AND C.COLUMN_NAME IN (SELECT CCU2.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU2
                                                        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC ON 
                                                        CCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                                                        AND CCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                                        AND CCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                                        WHERE TC.TABLE_NAME = HL.TABLENAME
                                                        AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY')
                                AND C.COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT 
                                                                C.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU3
                                                                ON C.TABLE_CATALOG = CCU3.TABLE_CATALOG
                                                                AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = CCU3.TABLE_SCHEMA 
                                                                AND C.TABLE_NAME = CCU3.TABLE_NAME
                                                                AND C.COLUMN_NAME =CCU3.COLUMN_NAME

                                                                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC ON 
                                                                CCU3.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
                                                                AND CCU3.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
                                                                AND CCU3.CONSTRAINT_NAME = TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
                                                                AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                                            WHERE   
                                                                C.TABLE_NAME 
                                                            IN (SELECT 
                                                                    HL4.TABLENAME FROM HUB_OR_LINK HL4 
                                                                WHERE 
                                                                    HL4.HUBORLINK = 'HUB'

                                                                ) --GET ALL HUBS
                                                            )


                                FOR XML PATH ('')
                            )
                            +  @LOAD_DATE_RS
                            + 'CONSTRAINT PK_LINK_' +REPLACE(HL.TABLENAME, ' ', '_') + '  PRIMARY KEY (' 
                            +(  SELECT  
                                    DISTINCT PK_TABLE+'_ID,'
                                FROM    
                                    FK_PK_REF
                                WHERE   
                                    FK_Table NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PK_Table FROM FK_PK_REF)
                                    AND FK_TABLE = HL.TABLENAME
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                             )

                            + '))'+CHAR(10)+CHAR(10)
                    FROM    HUB_OR_LINK HL INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
                    ON
                            T.TABLE_NAME = HL.TABLENAME
                    WHERE   HL.HUBORLINK = 'LINK'
                    FOR XML PATH (''))

SELECT @CREATE_LINK_M_N_RELN = REPLACE(@CREATE_LINK_M_N_RELN,',))','))');
PRINT @CREATE_LINK_M_N_RELN
```

The part that is adding the primary keys of the source table to the definition from the comment --GET PRIMARY KEYS --HAS SOME PROBLEMS to  @LOAD_DATE_RS. If that part returns a blank output (meaning there are no tables with extra primary keys) then the whole output is blank. How do I stop this? If that part is blank then still I need to get the other dynamic SQL built so that I can execute it to get the tables I want. Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "Blank" do you mean an empty string or `Null`? If it is null, You could wrap an `IsNull()` around that portion of the concatenation.

If you run the troubling section on it's own without `For XML Path('')`, does it return all of the expected values?

Comment: It gives an empty string with XML PATH. 

Running just the troubled section gives no output for database that does not have any . 'no column name' and nothing. If it has an output it gives it with our without xml path.